# in R shiny app File,choose() and dlgsave() Functions are not working properly in shiny.io

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server

I deployed my app in shiny.io. its working some of the java script codings and functions are not working properly. **file.choose() & dlgsave()** these two functions and **Javascript codes** are not working remaining all things are working.

```
save(dlgSave(title = 'Save script to', filters = myfilter[c('R', 'All'), ])$res)
```

and

```
p<-source(file.choose())
```

i added these two function for different purposes, but if i access these two function over the options in my shiny app. Then sever will get disconnected. Even some of the java scripts are also not working. **these two functions are working in my local host** but its not working **shiny.io**. is there any solution for this problem???

Thanks in Adavnce.